# I need help resetting my repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket

I currently have a private repository on bitbucket which I use for developing my app on my laptop and desktop.  On my laptop I started working on a new branch called **bootstrap**.  I cloned it from **origin/master**.  Unfortunately, I forgot to publish my **local master** first.  Not realizing this, I then made 3 commits to the remote.  This made the commits to **origin/master** and the remote does not have the **bootstrap** branch.

I then tried to push my **local master** commits, but it tells me I have the 3 incoming commits.  I didn't realize all of this until I pulled on my desktop and everything is a mess.  I have no idea how to proceed to fix this and I desperately need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> everything is a mess

Then don't touch it.

- Clone again your repo in another local repo: at least, everything will be reset.
- add your first local repo as a remote to the second: `git remote add first ../firstRepo`
- `git fetch first`

Then:

- make your `bootstrap` branch in that new local repo: `git checkout -b bootstrap`
- through a [nice log](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/6309): `git log --oneline --graph -all --branches`, seek your new commits in `remotes/first`, and [cherry-pick them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309) to your current bootstrap branch.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm still a newb with git.  I was thinking of just scrapping the bootstrap branch, completely removing the remote repository from bitbucket, then republishing the master from my laptop (which is the correct branch) back to bitbucket.  Then I would pull that to my desktop after I deleted the old one.  Would this work?

Comment: @merlot possibly, but do it in a separate clone. Don't touch your first one.

Comment: Ok, I created a clone of my local repo.  However, it only contains the master branch (which is ok), but what if I need an un-merged branch? I suppose I could recreate it and manually copy changes from the old repo?

Comment: @merlot you fetch the old repo as I mention and you can then import the commit you want through cherry-picking.

Comment: Thanks for the help - back in business!